# Vector identity to rewrite triple product with gradient into divergence

Tags: vector-analysis, tensor-products, divergence-operator

Is there a vector identity that can rewrite a product of type

$$ \mathbf{a}\cdot(\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{a}), $$

where $\mathbf{a}$ is a vector, into a divergence, for example of the form

$$ \mathbf{a}\cdot(\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{a})= \nabla\cdot(|\mathbf{a}|^2 \mathbf{a}) + ... ? $$

I have had no luck so far in trying to employ any of the well known vector identities, but it feels like something like this should be possible

Comment: $a \cdot (a \cdot \nabla a)$ is a vector field, but $\nabla \cdot (|a|^2 a)$ is a real-valued function?

Comment: @aschepler $\mathbf{a}\cdot(\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{a})$ is also scalar, right?

Comment: $(\mathbf{a} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{a})$ is a scalar. Is the outer dot a scalar multiplication? It can't be a dot/inner product.

Comment: @aschepler $(\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{a})$ is a vector, since the $\nabla\mathbf{a}$ is rank 2, right? You can read it as $(\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{a}$ alternatively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am interpretting your product as $$\mathbf{a}\cdot\left[\left(\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla\right)\mathbf{a}\right]=\mathbf{a}\cdot\left(\sum_i a_i\partial_i \mathbf{a}\right)=\sum_{ij}a_i a_j\partial_i a_j.$$
The divergence you use as an example can be written as
$$\nabla\cdot\left(|\mathbf{a}|^2\mathbf{a}\right)=\sum_{ij}\partial_i\left(a_j^2 a_i\right)=2\sum_{ij}a_ia_j\partial_ia_j+\sum_{ij}a_j^2\partial_ia_i.$$
Identifying
$$\sum_{ij}a_j^2\partial_ia_i=|\mathbf{a}|^2\left(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{a}\right),$$ your desired identity could be
$$\mathbf{a}\cdot\left[\left(\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla\right)\mathbf{a}\right]=\frac{1}{2}\left[\nabla\cdot\left(|\mathbf{a}|^2\mathbf{a}\right) - |\mathbf{a}|^2\left(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{a}\right)\right].$$

Here I have used the shorthand $\partial_i=\partial/\partial i$.

Comment: I think you cracked the nut here, thanks! I'll give it a deeper look and report back

Comment: A wise man once told me that all vector calculus identities are easier to derive when you write the coordinates explicitly